# css box with two different shapes

Tags: html, css

Can anyone write the code to display this shape?
The code so far

**html**

```
<a class="steps_boxes" href="#"></a>
```

**css**

```
.steps_boxes {
    width:22%;
    height:auto;
    background:#e7f4ef;
    border-radius:6px;
    float:left;
    margin:0 2%;
    padding:20px 0;
}
.steps_boxes:hover {
    background:#ff7429;
}
a.steps_boxes {
    color:#119865;
    font-size:28px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
a.steps_boxes:hover {
    color:#fff;
}
```

I do not have 10 reputation to post image, It's basically a rectangle with a semi circle on the bottom center of the rectangle. Can email the pic to anyone who can help.

Comment: Simply post a link to your image, no one can understand your question as it is.

Comment: okay its a round edged rectangle that changes color on hover .. what do you want to do with it?

Comment: As a note the future. You wont gain reputation by asking people to "write the code". We aren't a coding service, if you would like someone to "write the code" then hire someone.

Comment: user3725880, see my answer and if you feel it answers the question don't forget to mark it as the correct answer, and or upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an answer based off of the one by damien hawks. I have included some jQuery so that both shapes change color on hover. You can adapt this to be closer to the code you had provided.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r2pm6/3/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="rectangle" class="hover"></div>
<div id="halfCircleBottom" class="hover"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.hover {
    background-color: #e7f4ef;
}
.hovered {
    background-color: #ff7429;
}
#rectangle {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
}
#halfCircleBottom {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height:45px;
    width:90px;
    border-radius: 0 0 90px 90px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 90px 90px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 90px 90px;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.hover').hover(function () {
        $('.hover').toggleClass('hovered');
    });
})
```

With this you can put the rectangle and half circle divs in a container and position them wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? I made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r2pm6/) doing that. Just click on the link and comment below regarding what exactly you want to do.

Simply used two css classes two make two different shapes and to get the circle to the centre of the rectangle have used `margin-left:50px;`

Comment: `margin-left:50px;` is off centre, `margin-left:56px` is more centred.

Comment: This is a far better JSFiddle as it is 100% truely centered http://jsfiddle.net/r2pm6/1/ . You could then through the image in a container div to move it wherever you want.

Comment: @damienhawks Look at my answer. I feel as though it is the intended result.